# Can't filter by geolocation field in SOQL

Tags: soql, geolocation

I'm trying to do a simple SOQL query to find all opportunities that have a null geolocation field, however, the query keeps blowing with:

> Save error: field 'Coordinates__c' can not be filtered in query call

Is it not possible to filter by geolocation fields? I haven't been able to find anything online that says so. I thought it might be because the field wasn't part of the select clause, so I added it in, but it didn't correct the error.

Can someone point me at what I'm missing?

Comment: This community has thrived for a long time on community moderation. 5 of our most experienced users agreed that you didn't provide enough code or context. Sarcasm and condescension are not vehicles to get people to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm) on how to use GEOLOCATION fields in SOQL

Essentially you will need to use DISTANCE function that calculates distance between two coordinates and then use GEOLOCATION() function in where clause .

An example query would look like below

```
SELECT Name, Coordinates__c FROM Warehouse__c WHERE DISTANCE(Coordinates__c, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'mi') < 20
```

Also note some limitations

1.DISTANCE and GEOLOCATION are supported in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses
   in SOQL, but not in GROUP BY. DISTANCE is supported in SELECT
   clauses.

2.DISTANCE supports only the logical operators > and <, returning
   values within (<) or beyond (>) a specified radius.

3.When using the GEOLOCATION function in SOQL queries, the geolocation
   field must precede the latitude and longitude coordinates. For
   example, DISTANCE(warehouse_location__c,
   GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'km') works but
   DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), warehouse_location__c, 'km')
   doesn’t work.

4.Apex bind variables aren’t supported for the units parameter in
   DISTANCE or GEOLOCATION functions.